# How to import JSON data with separated field definitionss into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

While this question might seem similar to another, it's not because the json file I want to import, that is generated by a large government agency, has two sections, the first section defines field labels and the second section contains data.

I want to import the following JSON file into an MySql table:

```
{
  "fields": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "email",
    "phone"
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      42,
      "Bernice",
      "bernice@gmail.com",
      "212-555-1212"
    ],
    [
      64,
      "Jimmy",
      "jimmy@gmail.com",
      "203-555-1212"
    ],
    [
      3,
      "Marvin",
      "marvin@gmail.com",
      "415-555-1212"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Available examples using JSON_TABLE() illustrate how to do this when the data is structured as follows:

```
{
    [
      "id": 42,
      "name": "Bernice",
      "email": "bernice@gmail.com",
      "phone": "212-555-1212"
    ],
    [
      "id": 64,
      "name": "Jimmy",
      "email": "jimmy@gmail.com",
      "phone": "203-555-1212"
    ],
    [
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Marvin",
      "email": "marvin@gmail.com",
      "phone": "415-555-1212"
    ]
}
```

Can this be accomplished in MySQL? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the table which you want this data to import into already exists, or it must be created? Does the data columns ordering within data arrays which is provided in the most upper structure definition array may be altered, or it is static always?

Comment: Looking up this description from mysql, the JSON_TABLE() method expects a certain format of your json. Yours looks like a csv-file is structured. Why not convert your existing JSON to the expected format?

It would probably help, if you could add any options you have available to deal with the JSON-file itself, if it's a one time task or a recurring one or what kind of solution you are looking for.

https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/

Answer (score 0):

The below query converts your JSON to EAV representation. Use any pivotting technique if you want to convert this data to common table-type representation.

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM JSON_TABLE(
    @json,
    '$.fields[*]' COLUMNS (
      name_id FOR ORDINALITY,
      column_name VARCHAR(64) PATH '$'
      )
    ) jsontable
  ), 
cte2 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM JSON_TABLE(
    @json,
    '$.data[*]' COLUMNS (
      data_id FOR ORDINALITY,
      NESTED PATH '$[*]' COLUMNS (
        name_id FOR ORDINALITY,
        data_value VARCHAR(100) PATH '$'
        )
      )
    ) jsontable
  )
SELECT data_id, column_name, data_value
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 USING (name_id)
ORDER BY data_id, name_id
```

| data_id | column_name | data_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id | 42 |
| 1 | name | Bernice |
| 1 | email | bernice@gmail.com |
| 1 | phone | 212-555-1212 |
| 2 | id | 64 |
| 2 | name | Jimmy |
| 2 | email | jimmy@gmail.com |
| 2 | phone | 203-555-1212 |
| 3 | id | 3 |
| 3 | name | Marvin |
| 3 | email | marvin@gmail.com |
| 3 | phone | 415-555-1212 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FcmVsJDh)

Comment: The file is from a government and its structure is static. Thank you for your assistance @Akina.